# Validate the user in AngularJS without any back end calls or Databases

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, single-page-application

I have created a static website using AngularJS. I am not using any backend calls or database. But I would like to have a login page where the user enters a password (password same for the site users as the site is for internal purposes only), if the password is correct then i take user to the home page else take them back to login scree. I am using Apache Web Server. Is there a way to achieve a safe validation/authentication in AngularJS without Tomcat/Database/Cookies etc ?

Note: I don't want to store username and password in any .js file in a way that it is exposed to any user.

Thanks

Comment: There is no way to do authorization strictly in browser. It has to be done on some server whether it's your own or a third party data service

Answer (score 4):

Real-world equivalent to only using #JavaScript for input validation.

[image]

sorry, for sarcasm.

Comment: and if you turn the handset over can call only 611

Answer (score 0):

Withouit a server, there is no full proof way of achieving this. However you can  encrypt the password and username and then store them in cookies. there are many javascript libraries out there for achieving this.
Sample tutorial: [Encrypt cookies in browser.](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/encrypting-cookies-in-the-browser)

This way its not exposed to user.

Comment: the encription key have to be stored in the client side no ?

Comment: Is there a way to do it without cookies ?

Comment: I don't see a perfect way of doing it on the client side at all.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add HTTP basic auth to your app. If you host your app with Aerobatic, you might configure this in your package.json like so (note that you can optionally add auth to specific directories):

https://www.aerobatic.com/docs/http-basic-authentication

disclaimer: I'm a co-founder of Aerobatic

```
{
  "_aerobatic": {
    "router": [
      {
        "module": "basic-auth",
        "path": "/protected",
        "options": {
          "username": "$BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME",
          "password": "$BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD",
          "loginPage": "login.html",
          "maxFailedLogins": 5,
          "failedLoginPeriod": 600
        }
      },
      {
        "module": "webpage"
      },
      {
        "module": "custom-errors",
        "errors": {
          "403": "403.html"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```